# Android: How to draw circle within two point?

Tags: android, canvas

this is my current code

```
Path path_eclipse = new Path();
float radius = (float) (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r.stopX - r.startX, 2.0f) + Math.pow(r.stopY - r.startY, 2.0f)) / 2.0f);
path_eclipse.addCircle(r.startX, r.startY, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);
canvas.drawPath(path_eclipse, paint);
```

with this code I am getting as output:

[image]

But I want to draw circle like this:

[image]

UPDATED Source code: This source code worked in my case
[SOLVED]

[OnDraw]

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Path path_eclipse = new Path();
        float centerX = (r.startX + r.stopX) /2;
        float centerY = (r.startY + r.stopY) /2;
        float radius = (float)Math.sqrt((r.stopX - r.startX)*(r.stopX - r.startX)+(r.stopY - r.startY)*(r.stopY - r.startY));
        path_eclipse.addCircle(centerX, centerY, radius/2, Path.Direction.CCW);
        canvas.drawPath(path_eclipse,paint);
}
```

[OnTouchEvent]

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startX = eventX;
                    startY = eventY;
                    return true;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    stopX = eventX;
                    stopY = eventY;
                    break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    stopX = eventX;
                    stopY = eventY;
                    break;
               default:
                    return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
}
```

Comment: divide your radius by 2, and center is the middle of the line between 2 points

Comment: Are those two exactly opposite? Or are they just two points on the circle?

Comment: Hello, It's two points get from onTouch event.

Comment: What I wanted was the first output you were initially getting and your question became my answer fortunately :D Thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two paramateres of [`addCircle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#addCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Path.Direction)) are the x and y coordinates of the center. Assuming A and B are the furthest distance from each other on the circle you want, then the center should a point equidistant to both, hence:

```
float centerX = (pointA.x + pointB.x) /2
float centerY = (pointA.y + pointB.y) /2
```

And your radius should be, the distance between A and B, thus:

```
float radius = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2−x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2−y1, 2))) / 2
```

Comment: Without knowing what `r`, `r.startX`, and `r.startY` is, this is all i can say

Comment: Hello, I added more source code, already try your solution but x,y coordinate is wrong.
path_eclipse.addCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);
This is the result: https://youtu.be/tT4RlQ_XWGc
Thank you.

Comment: But `Math.pow()` requires 2 parameters? I think you're missing the power to param.

Answer (score 1):

Mid points

```
 int mx=(r.stopX + r.startX)/2;
 int my= (r.stopy+r.startY)/2;
```

Radius

```
float radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r.stopX - my, 2)
        + Math.pow(r.stopY - my, 2));
```

**Edited**

I have used code below

```
public class CustomView extends View {
  private Paint paint;
  private Circle circle;
  private List<Point> points;
  public final int CIRCLE_BETWEEN_TWO_POINTS = 1;
  private int viewType;

  {
    paint = new Paint();
    points = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    switch (viewType) {
      case CIRCLE_BETWEEN_TWO_POINTS:
        drawView(canvas);
        break;
    }
  }

  private void drawView(Canvas canvas){
    for(Point point:points){
      drawCircle(canvas,new Circle(point.x,point.y,10),false);
    }
    drawCircle(canvas,circle,true);
  }

  private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas,Circle circle, boolean isStroke){
    paint.reset();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    if(isStroke){
      paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
      paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }else {
      paint.setColor(Color.RED);
      paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    canvas.drawCircle(circle.getX(), circle.getY(), circle.getRadius(), paint);
  }

  public void drawCircleBetweenTwoPoints(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    viewType = CIRCLE_BETWEEN_TWO_POINTS;
    points.clear();
    points.add(new Point(x1, y1));
    points.add(new Point(x2, y2));
    int mx = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    int my = (y1 + y2) / 2;
    double radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - mx, 2)
      + Math.pow(y1 - my, 2));
    circle=new Circle(mx,my,(int)radius);
    invalidate();
  }


}
```

And called method as

```
customView.drawCircleBetweenTwoPoints(500,200,100,600);
```

and its working for me

[Click to see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5vpI.png)

Comment: Hello, I followed your solution but still not work, I think it's because of this code.
path_eclipse.addCircle(mx, my, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);
Here is the result: youtu.be/tT4RlQ_XWGc
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw circle like this, you must know 3 points, then calculate center with radius. Because two points cannot uniquely determine a circle. You can find only whole line of possible centers.

On the other hand, if we consider that two points are exactly opposite. Then you should calculate center by midpoint formula:

**M = [(x1 + x2 / 2), (y1 + y2 / 2)]**

Next, you can do the same thing as at first case. First, calculate radius and then draw circle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that **A** and **B** are exactly opposite to each other, the line segment defined by them will pass through the centre of the circle (**C**), and the latter will cut **AB** in half.

Thus:

You calculate then distance of the two points, and divide by two. So you'll have the radius.

The centre of the circle will be exactly halfway between the two: `x=(x1+x2)/2` and `y=(y1+y2)/2`.

If they happen to be just random points, you can use one of these techniques:

- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220000323/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54490.html)
- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128170023/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53027.html)

In this case however, your problem is slightly tricky, as two points and a radius will not determine one circle unambiguously: the problem will have two solutions.